# Research on Pre-Columbian Polynesian geometry?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, geometry

Has there been any historical/cultural anthropological research into how Polynesian cultures understood geometry before contact with Europeans? In part what I am interested in is how did the dealing with the problems of navigating on a scale where the spherical nature of the earth influence their understanding of space and shapes.

Just from browsing google I can see that a lot of Polynesian art seems to have an awareness of this but I know this could be because of my biasies when interpreting the art.

Comment: For Pacific Islander cultures navigation did not work on the European model, so issues of spherical trigonometry and geometry did not arise (best I know). For an example, see ["Navigating the Waters with Micronesian Stick Charts"](https://ocean.si.edu/human-connections/history-cultures/navigating-waters-micronesian-stick-charts)